# the lamda function cannot run for time comparison

Tags: python, lambda

I have a lambda function to use a dictionary to run power on/power off schedules. Basically, I defined the power off time for each day in a dictionary variable "app_off = {'Monday': '20:52', 'Tuesday': '22:00', 'Wednesday': '20:00', 'Thursday': '22:00', 'Friday': '20:00'}". The lambda function is triggered every minute by the cloudwatch event.

Supposedly, on a specific time of the day (defend day of the week), the current_time should be equal to the specified time in the dictionary variable and then the ec2 instance got powered down and powered on. But for some reason, my lambda function has not run successfully. The log file still shows the records from "2021-04-26T20:24:42.925-07:00". Please help me taking a look to see where is wrong.

```py
import boto3
import time

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get current time in format H:M
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    current_dayoftheweek = time.strftime("%A")
    print(f'The current time: {current_time}')
    print(f'The current day of the week is: {current_dayoftheweek}')

    # Find all the instances that are tagged with Scheduled:True
    filters = [{
        'Name': 'tag:Lambda_Managed',
        'Values': ['Yes']
    }
    ]

    # Search all the instances which contains scheduled filter
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    # Define different schedule groups and start/stop time.
    
    # Application server schedule group
    app_off = {'Monday': '20:52', 'Tuesday': '22:00', 'Wednesday': '20:00', 'Thursday': '22:00', 'Friday': '20:00'}
    app_on = {'Monday': '5:00', 'Tuesday': '5:00', 'Wednesday': '7:00', 'Thursday': '5:00', 'Friday': '7:00', 'Saturday': '5:00'}
    
    # Web server schedule group
    web_off = {'Monday': '20:00', 'Tuesday': '22:00', 'Wednesday': '20:00', 'Thursday': '22:00', 'Friday': '20:00'}
    web_on = {'Monday': '5:00', 'Tuesday': '5:00', 'Wednesday': '7:00', 'Thursday': '5:00', 'Friday': '7:00', 'Saturday': '5:00'}
    
    # SQL server schedule group
    sql_off = {'Monday': '20:00', 'Tuesday': '22:00', 'Wednesday': '20:00', 'Thursday': '22:00', 'Friday': '20:00'}
    sql_on = {'Monday': '5:00', 'Tuesday': '5:00', 'Wednesday': '7:00', 'Thursday': '5:00', 'Friday': '7:00', 'Saturday': '5:00'}
    
    # Stores list of instanceIDs
    stopInstances = []
    startInstances = []

    # Locate all instances that are tagged to start or stop.
    # ======crontab format===========
    # App Schedule Group:

    # minute  hour  (day of month)  month (day of week)

    # Power Off Triggers:
    # 0 20 * * 1,3,5
    # 0 22 * * 2,4
    # 
    # Power On Triggers:
    # 0 5 * * 1,2,4,6
    # 0 7 * * 3,5
    
    for instance in instances:

        for tag in instance.tags:

            if tag['Key'] == 'Schedule_Name':

                if tag['Value'] == 'App' and current_time == app_off["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    stopInstances.append(instance.id)

                pass

                
                if tag['Value'] == 'Web' and current_time == web_off["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    stopInstances.append(instance.id)

                pass


                if tag['Value'] == 'Sql' and current_time == sql_off["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    stopInstances.append(instance.id)

                pass

            

            if tag['Key'] == 'Schedule_Name':

                if tag['Value'] == 'App' and current_time == app_on["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    if instance.state['Name'] == 'stopped':

                        startInstances.append(instance.id)
                    pass
                pass

                if tag['Value'] == 'Web' and current_time == web_on["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    if instance.state['Name'] == 'stopped':

                        startInstances.append(instance.id)
                    pass
                pass

                if tag['Value'] == 'Sql' and current_time == sql_on["current_dayoftheweek"]:

                    if instance.state['Name'] == 'stopped':

                        startInstances.append(instance.id)
                    pass
                pass
            pass

        pass

    #print('current_time')
    print(f'The current time: {current_time}')
    print(f'The current day of the week is: {current_dayoftheweek}')

    # shut down all instances tagged to stop.
    if len(stopInstances) > 0:
        # perform the shutdown
        stop = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=stopInstances).stop()
        print(f"Stopping instance: {stopInstances} - {current_time}")
    else:
        print("No instances to shutdown.")

    # start instances tagged to stop.
    if len(startInstances) > 0:
        # perform the start
        start = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=startInstances).start()
        print(f"Starting instance: {startInstances} - {current_time}")
    else:
        print("No instances to start.")
```

Comment: Any comment will be great appreciated, I got stucked here for a few days. The cloudwatch was set to trigger once per minute and it is indeed triggers the lambda function.

Comment: What are you observing instead? Is it erroring? Is it just not running at all? Maybe your trigger isn't functioning correctly?